# Docker composer подключиться к MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

Есть 2 контейнера (*Вроде это так называется*)

`Mongo` и `Server`

Как подключиться из контейнера `Server` к `Mongo` по Адресу 127.0.0.1

Вот моя yml'ка

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  db:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    hostname: "mongodb.local"
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
  server:
    build: server
    restart: always
    hostname: "server.local"
    links:
      - "db:mongodb"
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - 5561:8080
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну по адресу 127.0.0.1 наверное не получится, если это отдельные контейнеры.
Отдельный контейнер это как отдельное устройство, а 127.0.0.1 предназначение для доступа внутри одного устройства.

Но у Вас есть возможность получить доступ к другому контейнеру по его имени, в данном случае *"db:27017"*
А также, если Вы планировали использовать для этого **hostname** и **links** то этого делать не нужно, этим занимается внутренний DNS.

docker-compose при запуске создает bridge интерфейс для связи контейнеров между собой, это как локальная сеть. И назначает каждому устройству в нем свое имя соответствующее имени сервиса docker-compose. Так они могут общаться между собой, а **ports:"27017:27017"** пробрасывает этот порт на Ваш loopback интерфейс, и теперь к нему можно получить доступ непосредственно из терминала устройства по адресу **localhost:27017**, но в большинстве случаев это не нужно(хотя может пригодится для отладки)

Comment: Спасибо за помощь! :)